# How to add index outside a table in latex

Tags: latex, tabular, pdflatex

How to add index outside a table like this?

[image: pic]

Thanks!

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please make a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. It should contain your current table, and all relevant classes/packages you're using. It would also be helpful if you go into more detail what your goal is, please tell us in a few sentences what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going out on a limb here, I assume you want to create the indeces in the smaller font size...
I extended the table and reduzed the font size for the indeces. Using the array package for the rest.

Minimal working the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                & {\scriptsize 1}          & {\scriptsize 2}       & {\scriptsize 3}         & {\scriptsize 4}         \\ \cline{2-5}
{\scriptsize 1} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ }& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-2}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } \\ \cline{2-5}
{\scriptsize 2} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } \\ \cline{2-5}
{\scriptsize 3} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ }& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } \\ \cline{2-5}
{\scriptsize 4} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ }& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0} \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With the following result:
[image]

You can choose a different font size for the indices, like `\small`, `\footnotesize` or `\tiny`.

Answer (score 0):

A basic version trying to reduce the number of `multicolumn`s used may be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c|}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4}\\\cline{2-5}
1                     & 0                     &                       & -2                    &                      \\\cline{2-5}
2                     &                       & 0                     &                       &                      \\\cline{2-5}
3                     &                       &                       & 0                     &                      \\\cline{2-5}
4                     &                       &                       &                       & 0                    \\\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]